# Swap is empty on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, swap

How can I create or resize the swap memory on a linux device (Amazon Linux AMI). The problem came when I run a program and it gave me that errors:

```
 IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): Waiting for existing lock by unknown process (I am process '947')
INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): To manually release the lock, delete /root/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.4.43-43.43.amzn1.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5-x86_64-2.6.8-64/lock_dir
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Something wrong happened: <type 'exceptions.IOError'> [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

When I execute the *free* to check out the memory of the device, the linux device printed me:

```
    total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      22058544    7581508   14477036          0     144316    7025740
-/+ buffers/cache:     411452   21647092
Swap:            0          0          0
```

How can I resize the swap to use it or create a new swap file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will be the same for you but I tried this and it worked.
You can try to use a swap file :

1. Create a file that will be used as the swap file with count being equal to the desired block size (here the size is 64MB)

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=65536
   ```
2. Enable the swap using the following:

   ```
   mkswap /swapfile
   ```
3. Check if the swap is really used:

   ```
   swapon -s
   ```
4. If everything seems alright you can add this line to /etc/fstab :

   ```
   /swapfile          swap            swap    defaults        0 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found the answer. What I had to do is that below to create the swap file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=10930193
```

Then to enable it just do:

```
mkswap /swapfile
```

Comment: This looks very close to [@NabilEchaouch's answer](http://superuser.com/a/628538/53590); if so, you should upvote and accept that (by clicking the green checkmark outline just below the voting arrows) rather than writing another answer of your own. You can delete your own answer afterwards as it adds nothing that isn't already in Nabil's answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Done! ;)